# Why multiplying a singular Matrix with another vecotr results in null

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, linear-independence

Given a square matrix M of dimension n : In order to find the set of eigenvalues of M one should solve the equation : 
$$\\M.X=\lambda.X \enspace \enspace \enspace  be \enspace \enspace \enspace (M-\lambda.I_{n}).X=0 \\ where \enspace \lambda \enspace is \enspace an \enspace eigenvalue \enspace of \enspace M \enspace and \enspace X \enspace is \enspace a \enspace non-nul \enspace column \enspace vector \enspace called \enspace the \enspace eigenvector \enspace of \enspace M \enspace relative \enspace to \enspace the \enspace eigenvalue \enspace \lambda$$

The french wikipedia [article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyn%C3%B4me_caract%C3%A9ristique#Motivation) states that since X is non-null, this means the matrix (M-λ.I) should be a singular matrix that is its deterimnent is equal to zero. My question is : What does the singularity of some matrix has to do with the nullability of its product with another vector ?

Comment: what conditions do you know for a matrix to have zero determinant?

Comment: The multiplication of a matrix by a column vector from the right is the same as a linear combination of the columns of the matrix using the coefficients of the vector. That the product is zero, means that the columns of the matrix are linearly dependent. The determinant of linearly dependent vectors is zero. This follows from the (multi-) linearity of the determinant and the fact that it changes signs when its columns are switched (alternating).

Comment: @Exodd : I always thought (in a mechanic way so to say) that computing the determinant serves only for calculating the inverse of some square matrix, never thought about this question before.

Comment: @YAlexandrov : Then what relationship there is please between the linear independency of some matrix's columns/rows with the non-nullability of its determinant?

Comment: @ecdhe I already said above. If $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are linearly dependent columns, then one of them, say $a_n$ is a linear combination of the others: $a_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}r_ia_i$. Therefore $det(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=det(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1},\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}r_ia_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}r_idet(a_1,...,a_{n-1},a_i)$. But in each of those determinants there is a repeated column. Therefore each of them is zero because switching those two columns is supposed to change the sign but the value doesn't change because it is the same determinant. The only number that remains the same after changing sign is $0$.

Comment: @YAlexandrov Thank you so much :) although this doesn't fully answer my question. In fact I would like to know why: $$ \enspace det(a_{1},...,a_{n-1}, a_{1}) = 0 \enspace  given \, i=1 \enspace  for \enspace  instance$$

Comment: The explanation is already in the previous comment. Determinants satisfy that $det(a,a_2,...,a_{n-1},b)=-det(b,a_2,...,a_{n-1},a)$. They change sign when you switch two columns. If $a=b$ then switching them gives you the same expression. Therefore $det(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1},a_1)$ is a number who's opposite is equal to itself. Therefore, it is zero.

Comment: @YAlexandrov : Perfect and more than satisfying answer. Thank you so much :)