# Linear dependency of a Matrix's columns and its relation with Matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

With regard to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2684875/why-multiplying-a-singular-matrix-with-another-vecotr-results-in-null?noredirect=1#comment5545030_2684875), I would like to know how come that if the product of a square matrix $M \in R_{n,n}$ with a non-null column vector $X \in R_{n,1}$ is $null$ then $M$'s columns or rows are linearly dependent. In a more formal way :

$M=(V_{1}, V_{2}, ..,V_{n}) \enspace and \enspace M.X=0 \enspace and\enspace  X\neq0 \Rightarrow  \exists \enspace V_{i} \enspace such\enspace as \enspace V_{i}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}.V_{k}$

Could someone please elaborate more on why this is true ? A reliable reference will be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the rows of your matrix  $M$ are are linearly independent.

Then the matrix $M$ is invertible.

That is, we have a matrix $M^{-1}$ such that $$M^{-1}M=I$$

Now if $MV=0$ for some $V\ne 0$, then $$ V= IV=(M^{-1}M)V=M^{-1}(MV)=0$$ which is a contradiction.

Thus if $MV=0$ for some $V\ne 0$ then the rows of $M$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $X = (x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)^T,$ then you can check that $MX = x_1V_1+x_2V_2+\dots+x_nV_n,$ so the statement is just the definition of linear independence.

Comment: You are right. In fact, this makes sense. For $(V_{i})_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ to be linearly independent, the following expression $T$ must be true :
$$T \enspace : \enspace \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}.V_{k}=0 \Rightarrow \forall k \enspace x_{k}=0$$
But since $X=(x_{1}, x_{2}, ...,x_{n})^{T}\enspace\neq\enspace0$ meaning that $\exists i \enspace such \enspace as \enspace x_{i}\neq0$ thus $T$ is false and $(V_{i})_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: @ecdhe Exactly.